# Find references to URL in SharePoint on premises

Tags: powershell, site-collection, central-administration, hyperlink, site-settings

Is there a Powershell script, or query, or an area in Central Administration, or in the Site settings etc, where I can check what pages reference a certain URL?

e.g.

http://mydomain/sites/collection1/page1.aspx

There might be a couple of other pages:

http://mydomain/sites/collection1/page2.aspx

http://mydomain/sites/collection1/page3.aspx

And where would be a html hyperlink in these pages that link to page1.aspx

I would like a query / report that lets me know that page2 and page 3 are referencing / linking to page 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer the Site Content and Structure report for this purpose.

**What is Site Content and Structure in SharePoint Server?**

SharePoint uses the Site Content and Structure page to manage both the content and structure of your SharePoint site collection. The Site Content and Structure page is available only when SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure is an activated site collection feature. The Site Content and Structure page supports move and copy functionality only when both of the following conditions are true:

- You're using any of the out-of-box default publishing templates.
- You're moving or copying pages or folders from the out-of-box Pages
  Library to another out-of-box Pages Library. The destination Pages Library can be either in the same library or a different library. However, the libraries must be in the same site collection.

MSDN Documentation:

[Supported scenarios for Site Content and Structure in SharePoint Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/supported-scenarios-for-site-content-and-structure-in-sharepoint-server-b9bccb8e-fa09-42ec-be0f-be97ca574d24?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

**How to access the site content and structure page?**

SiteURL/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx